# Intel Galileo IoT Visual Studio Issue

Tags: visual-studio, intel-galileo, windowsondevices

I haven't any other working ways of communication with WindowsOnDevices community (given on site https://ms-iot.github.io/content/ContactUs.htm) so I'm trying to ask here. 
I got Intel Galileo from Microsoft IoT program, connection is working, I can ping it, watch files on SD card, do something via Telnet, etc. Microsoft gives SDK for Galileo in **Visual Studio Express 2013**. I installed it and configure as they told on https://ms-iot.github.io/content/, so I wanted to launch "Hello world" blinking LED app from their site, debugging over ethernet. I press F5 or click Debug in Visual Studio, it writes me "Operation is taking longer than expected" so I waited for 5, 10 and 15 minutes but nothing happend. Only in console "1>------ Deploy started: Project: Blink, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------"
I turned off all firewalls, it doesn't helped. When I kill remote debugger app (**msvsmon.exe**) on Galileo, it doesn't starts, so it can see this app on device. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use the default name for your Galileo ("mygalileo"), you'll have to [enter your board's name in the Project Properties](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/AdvancedUsage.htm#collapseRemoteDebugging).